# Parse Irregular table

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

Notice this complex table. For many of the rows on the left like "finite forms", "past", and "future", they have "rowSpan" equal to something greater than 1.

If I wanted to parse a simple table that has no row (or col-)Span attributes, then I would simply get table.rows and get the index of each row as the column, and determine what categories the cells belong to based on that.

The rowSpan and colSpan attributes of this table make things more complex, because if I get table.rows then the row at the beginning of "past" really has "past" then "first" then the next word (in this case דַּשְׁתִּי‎).

If that pattern repeated for the rows after, then it would be fine because I would be able to determine what category and sub cateogry of the row each cell belonged to (in this case it would be that the word דַּשְׁתִּי‎ (and דַּשְׁנוּ‎ on that same row) would be under the row categories of "past" and "first" (as well as each in it's own column cateogry, for דַּשְׁנוּ‎  plural [m,f] and for דַּשְׁתִּי‎ singular [m, f])).

However, with rowSpan set to 3 in the "past" row area, the next row under "first" ("second" in this case) is the first element of the new array, even though the "past" cell really preceeds it in the HTML (and in the way I want to parse the table in JavaScript).

To simplify the question:

I need to parse a complex table, in JavaScript, which may contain rowSpan and colSpan attributes.

My goal is to get the inner cells of the table and it's corresponding row and columns categories (in this case, there are two categories for both row and column (skipping the "non-finite forms" row at the top), I want a result as an array of objects where each object represents an inner cell, containing meta information about the row categories and column categories that cell belongs to.

In our example of the word דַּשְׁתִּי‎, the result should be some kind of JavaScript object (in an array) like this

content: דַּשְׁתִּי‎

row: 1 (assuming we start counting from the first inner word after categories start)

column: 1

rowCategories: [past, first]

columnCategories: [singular, [m,f]]

For the next word, the result would be almost the same except the columnCategories would be [plural, [m, f]].

And so too for all of the other inner cells.

Ideally I am looking for a function that takes in arguments specifying how many row and column categories there are (in this case, 2 each), dynamically being able to parse a table with any amount of them.

I have been trying to figure this out, but not able to just think how to properly parse the table to represent the row categories in front as well as the column categories properly to be able to cross reference them and organize them properly, given the rowSpan and colSpan attributes.

As you can see in the below snippet, I tried keeping track of rowSpan and colSpan but no matter what I try all of the categories get messed up and I can't figure out how to organize it properly.

```js
//B"H

function parseTableWithSpans(table) {
  const matrix = []; 
  const maxRowSpan = new Map(); 

  // A helper function to add cell info to the matrix.
  function addCellToMatrix(rowIdx, colIdx, cellText, rowSpan, colSpan) {
    for (let r = rowIdx; r < rowIdx + rowSpan; r++) {
      if (!matrix[r]) {
        matrix[r] = [];
      }
      for (let c = colIdx; c < colIdx + colSpan; c++) {
        matrix[r][c] = cellText;
        maxRowSpan.set(c, Math.max(maxRowSpan.get(c) || 1, rowSpan));
      }
    }
  }

  // Parsing the table.
  const rows = table.rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = rows[i];
    for (let j = 0, realIndex = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = row.cells[j];

      // Adjust realIndex for the active rowSpans.
      while (matrix[i] && matrix[i][realIndex] !== undefined) {
        realIndex++;
      }

      const rowSpan = cell.rowSpan || 1;
      const colSpan = cell.colSpan || 1;
      addCellToMatrix(i, realIndex, cell.textContent.trim(), rowSpan, colSpan);
      realIndex += colSpan;
    }

    // Decrease all active rowSpans by 1 as we move to the next row.
    for (let [colIdx, span] of maxRowSpan.entries()) {
      if (span > 1) maxRowSpan.set(colIdx, span - 1);
      else maxRowSpan.delete(colIdx);
    }
  }

  
  const result = [];
  matrix.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (rowIndex > 1) { 
      row.forEach((content, colIndex) => {
        if (colIndex > 1) { 
          result.push({
            content: content,
            row: rowIndex - 1, // Adjust index to skip category headers
            column: colIndex - 1, // Adjust index to skip category headers
            rowCategories: [matrix[0][colIndex], matrix[rowIndex][0]],
            columnCategories: [matrix[1][colIndex], matrix[rowIndex][1]]
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return result;
}

var p = parseTableWithSpans(myTable)
console.log(p)
```

```html
<!--B"H-->
<div class="NavContent" align="center">
<h2>B"H</h2>
<table id="myTable" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;line-height:2em;border:2px solid #000000;background:#fdfdfd;text-align:center" class="inflection-table">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="row" colspan="2" style="background:#E4C0CF;border-right:2px solid">non-finite forms
</th>
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:left">
<ul><li><b>to-infinitive:</b> <span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="לדוש (page does not exist)">לָדוּשׁ</a></span>‎</li>
<li><b>action noun:</b> <span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דישה (page does not exist)">דִּישָׁה</a></span>‎</li></ul>
</td></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="background:#E4C0CF;border-right:2px solid">finite forms
</th>
<th scope="col" colspan="2" style="background:#C0CFE4">singular
</th>
<th scope="col" colspan="2" style="background:#C0CFE4">plural
</th></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="col" style="background:#C0CFE4">m.
</th>
<th scope="col" style="background:#C0CFE4">f.
</th>
<th scope="col" style="background:#C0CFE4">m.
</th>
<th scope="col" style="background:#C0CFE4">f.
</th></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th scope="row" rowspan="3" style="background:#E2E4C0;width:1px">past
</th>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid;width:1px">first
</th>
<td colspan="2"><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%99&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשתי (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁתִּי</a></span>‎</td>
<td colspan="2"><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%95&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשנו (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁנוּ</a></span>‎
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid">second
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%AA&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשת (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁתָּ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%AA&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשת (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁתְּ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9D&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשתם (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁתֶּם</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9F&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשתן (page does not exist)">דַּשְׁתֶּן</a></span>‎
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid">third
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><strong class="selflink">דָּשׁ</strong></span></td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשה (page does not exist)">דָּשָׁה</a></span>‎</td>
<td colspan="2"><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשו (page does not exist)">דָּשׁוּ</a></span>‎
</td></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th scope="row" colspan="2" style="background:#E2E4C0;border-right:2px solid">present
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><strong class="selflink">דָּשׁ</strong></span></td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשה (page does not exist)">דָּשָׁה</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשים (page does not exist)">דָּשִׁים</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דשות (page does not exist)">דָּשׁוֹת</a></span>‎
</td></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th scope="row" rowspan="3" style="background:#E2E4C0">future
</th>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid">first
</th>
<td colspan="2"><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="אדוש (page does not exist)">אָדוּשׁ</a></span>‎</td>
<td colspan="2"><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="נדוש (page does not exist)">נָדוּשׁ</a></span>‎
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid">second
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדוש (page does not exist)">תָּדוּשׁ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדושי (page does not exist)">תָּדוּשִׁי</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%95&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדושו (page does not exist)">תָּדוּשׁוּ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדושנה (page does not exist)">תדושנה \ תָּדֹשְׁנָה</a></span>‎<sup>1</sup>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="background:#C0CFE4;border-right:2px solid">third
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="ידוש (page does not exist)">יָדוּשׁ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדוש (page does not exist)">תָּדוּשׁ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%95&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="ידושו (page does not exist)">יָדוּשׁוּ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="תדושנה (page does not exist)">תדושנה \ תָּדֹשְׁנָה</a></span>‎<sup>1</sup>
</td></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th scope="row" colspan="2" style="background:#E2E4C0;border-right:2px solid">imperative
</th>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9#Hebrew" title="דוש">דּוּשׁ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דושי (page does not exist)">דּוּשִׁי</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%95&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דושו (page does not exist)">דּוּשׁוּ</a></span>‎</td>
<td><span class="Hebr" lang="he"><a href="/w/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="דושנה (page does not exist)">דושנה \ דֹּשְׁנָה</a></span>‎<sup>1</sup>
</td></tr>
<tr style="border-top:2px solid">
<th scope="row" colspan="2" style="background:#E4C0CF;border-right:2px solid">notes
</th>
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:1px;padding-right:1em">
<ol><li>Rare in Modern Hebrew.</li></ol>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to turn the table into a 2d array while splitting `colspan` and `rowspan` to the equivalent cells having same value. So that `<td colspan="2">value</td>` will be `<td>value</td><td>value</td>`

My algorithm is first to create the `result` 2d array. Then for each row, we iterate on the cols and keeping a separate column index for the target array, `tj`. This is because target cell values may be occupied by a different cell from a previous row. Now for each cell we transfer its value to the same square(s) of the target array at `tj` index.

```js
function tableToArray(table) {
  const rows = table.rows
  var height = rows.length

  if (!rows.length) {
    return []
  }
  
  // counting columns by first row
  var row = rows[0]
  var width = 0
  for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
    const cell = row.cells[j];
    const colSpan = cell.colSpan || 1
    width += colSpan
  }

  // initialize result array with nulls (empties)
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    result[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      result[i][j] = null
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    const row = rows[i]
    var tj = 0 // target j

    for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {

      const cell = row.cells[j]
      const rowSpan = cell.rowSpan || 1
      const colSpan = cell.colSpan || 1
      const value = cell.innerText

      // skip over occupied cells
      while (tj < width && result[i][tj] != null) {
        tj += 1
      }

      // copy value to target cell(s)
      for (let rowIndex = i; rowIndex < i + rowSpan; rowIndex++) {
        for (let colIndex = tj; colIndex < tj + colSpan; colIndex++) {
          result[rowIndex][colIndex] = value
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return result;
}

pre.innerText = (tableToArray(table).map(line => line.join(', ')).join('\n'))
```

```css
[colspan] {
  background: red;
}

[rowspan] {
  background: blue;
}

[colspan][rowspan] {
  background: purple;
}

pre {
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; align-items: start">
  <table id="table" border="1" style="width: 180px; border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; ">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">A</td>
      <td rowspan="2">B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan=2>G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">H</td>
      <td>I</td>
      <td>J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">M</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>O</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td rowspan="2">Q</td>
      <td colspan="2">R</td>
      <td>S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td colspan="2">U</td>
      <td>V</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <pre id="pre"></pre>
</div>
```